# Kibana: Use timestamp from log file instead of @timestamp

Tags: timestamp, histogram, kibana

I am trying to use the timestamps that are in my log files. However, these timestamps have the following format, that is different from logstash's `@timestamp` field.

```
2014-10-31 02:45:09,355
```

When attempting to use my field related to the timestamps in my log files, the histogram is not displayed. I have changed the "Time field" in the "Timepicker" tab of my dashboard's settings accordingly, as well as in the histogram's settings.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Below is what I currently have in my filter:

```
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ".\patterns"
        match => [ "message", "%{LOGTIMESTAMP:tstamp}" ]
    }
    date {
        locale => "en"
        timezone => "Europe/Paris"
        match => [ "tstamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
        target => "tstamp"
    }
}
```

**As for my regular expression:**

```
LOGTIMESTAMP (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})
```

With this configuration, I obtain the following error: "Failed parsing date from field"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Id like to have added this as comment, but I don't have the reputation... anyway, I'm guessing that Kibana thinks your datetime is a string, not a type date (check the mapping,
`http://localhost:9200/_mapping?pretty` or whatever).

I had a similar problem, but followed this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html

However, any mapping I did didn't work, until I output it in this **exact** format `2014-12-03T09:04:02`.  (If I dropped the T it wouldn't work)

My advice is try to transform that log file time to match as I wasnt able to get Kibana to take any other format.

Comment: I updated my original post. With the configuration I currently have, I am not even able to save the data. Adding the "T" unfortunately did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "date" filter to tell Logstash about the date format - it will then convert your timestamp from the file into the @timestamp field.

Take a look here: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date

Comment: Why are you doing "target => "tstamp"" ? My understanding is that @timestamp is the magical field that elasticsearch uses and you should just stick with it.

At least, it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time to figure it out but the following format works for me for searching entries between specific times (2015 May 27 11am to 1130am to be exact)-

@timestamp:[1432704600000 TO 1432706400000]

Kibana requires timestamp in milliseconds from epoch format.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for the same log pattern "2014-10-31 02:45:09,355". This configuration worked for me.

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}" ]
}
date {
    locale => "en"
    timezone => "Europe/Paris"
    match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    target => ["tstamp"]
    remove_field => ["timestamp"]
}
```